# SQL: Delete from multiple tables using Joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, mysqli

The following will work if each of the three tables yields results, however if just one of these tables chucks nothing, then it breaks the query and doesn't delete anything. Is there a way to bulletproof this query so if just 1 of the three tables has results, they will be deleted?

```
DELETE e, f, c
FROM `users exercises` e
inner join `users foods` f on f.userid = e.userid and f.`date` = e.`date`
inner join `users check-ins` c on c.userid = e.userid and c.`date` = e.`date`
WHERE e.`date` = '$date' AND e.userid = '$user->id'
```

Comment: try changing `INNER JOIN` into `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Changing to LEFT JOIN has it working only if the 'users exercises' table yields results.

Comment: 'users exercises' needs to yield results in order for the delete to work due to the `ON` clause of your joins. If there are no 'user exercises' results, then there are no ids to match on 'users foods' and 'users check-ins'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a 'users' table? If so, then you can write something like this:

```
DELETE e, f, c
FROM 'users' u
left join 'users exercises' e on e.userid = u.userid and e.`date` = '$date'
left join 'users foods' f on f.userid = u.userid and f.`date` = '$date'
left join 'users check-ins' c on c.userid = u.userid and c.`date` = '$date'
WHERE u.userid = '$user->id'
```

Comment: I do, but will this delete the user? I don't want to delete the user.

Comment: You're only specifying to delete e, f, and c, so it should only delete from those 3 tables.